# how to write fuzzy match for large amount of value

Tags: sql, hive

I have two dataframes, one contains 100,000,000 above string texts. Another contains 2,000,000 words. How to use hive sql to do a like '%words%' match to the names efficiently? It runs forever so may need a sufficient solutions to run it faster.

texts
hellohello
summarize
describecode
wheretoeat

words
lohe
mar
ribe
to

thanks!

Comment: already tried tranform, concat('%', column name, '%') but still runs forever

Comment: Tokenize the sentences (split to words) and then join to the words table. I hope you have a very good reason to use Hive in 2022.

Comment: P.s. you don't have dataframes is Hive, which makes me wonder if you are actually using Hive or you're confusing Hive with Spark.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz solved thru  join two tables on 1=1, where locate(words,texts) > 0

Comment: Not really different from what you originally did. What was the execution time?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz data are stored on hdfs, i can use hivesql/mysql/etc to get the dataset.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz little bit faster because I limits the number of words instead

Comment: Could you share the execution time?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz 8,000,000,000 rows x 400 match, 7hrs 20 mins

Comment: Try the tokenization. You'll be surprised :-)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz could you elaborate how to tokenize the sentences?

Comment: `sentences(string str, string lang, string locale)` https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf